# Fill empty matrix with matrix using overlap in R

Tags: r, matrix

I would like to paste from i=1 to i=N a small matrix, l, into a large empty one, m. I would like to paste the matrix l with a gap of 1 column and 1 line and overwrite where it is overlapping.
[image]

Here my code:

```
ncol <- 12
G <- 3
m = matrix(, nrow = ncol, ncol = ncol)
l <- matrix(1:(G*G), nrow = G, ncol = G)
N <- ncol-(G)

for (i in (0:(N))) {
  for(j in (0:(N))){
  m[c(i+1, i+G), c(j+1, j+G)] <- l
  }
}
```

I have the following error message

```
Error in m[c(i + 1, i + G), c(j + 1, j + G)] <- l : 
  number of items to replace is not a multiple of replacement length
```

When I use G=2 it's fine, why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can use `replicate` :

```
do.call(cbind,replicate(ncol/2, matrix(1:4, nrow = 2,ncol = 2),simplify = FALSE))

#     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6] [,7] [,8] [,9] [,10]
#[1,]    1    3    1    3    1    3    1    3    1     3
#[2,]    2    4    2    4    2    4    2    4    2     4
```

---

To use `for` loop we can do :

```
ncol <- 10
m = matrix(, nrow = 2, ncol = ncol)
l <- matrix(1:4, nrow = 2, ncol = 2)
N <- ncol/2

for (i in (0:(N-1))) {
   j <- i * 2
   m[, c(j+1, j+2)] <- l
}
```

Comment: Thanks but I would like to overwrite each time the common column. Each iteration I paste the matrix, l, in the column i+1

Comment: I am not sure if I understand correctly but perhaps you meant using `for` loop. I have updated the answer, let me know if that is what you are looking for.

Comment: Great. I just modified it little bit as follow: N <- ncol-2
for (i in (0:(N))) {
  j <- i
  m[, c(j+1, j+2)] <- l
}